# How to adjust spacing between caption and table / figure in beamer?

Tags: tables, beamer, captions, warnings

I want to adjust spacing between caption and table/figure in beamer. However I am not able to overcome the warning

> Package caption Warning: \caption will not be redefined since it's
>   already (caption) redefined by a document class or package which is
>   (caption) unknown to the caption package.

I have tried by using `caption` and `subfig` packages. I used the command `\captionsetup{skip=0pt,belowskip=0pt}`. I am unable to overcome the warning. *EDIT: I wish to add that I am trying to modify (reduce) the spacing in this frame. For other frames I am okay with the default spacing.*

I need following format for my frame.

`MWE` the way it appears to me is

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\mode<presentation> {\usetheme{Madrid}}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Allows including images
\usepackage{booktabs} % Allows the use of \toprule, \midrule and \bottomrule in tables
\usepackage{lmodern}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lm
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{subfig}
%   \usepackage{caption}
\graphicspath{{Images/}} % path for images

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Results: Measurement of Length}
    \begin{picture}(0,200)
    \put(-5,210){
        \begin{minipage}[t]{0.48\linewidth}
            \setbeamerfont{caption}{size=\tiny} 
            \captionsetup[figure]{skip=0pt}%,belowskip=0pt}
            \begin{figure}
                \includegraphics[width=4.5cm, height=3cm]{C5.S.Results/Slide1.png} 
                \caption{Calibration: 1mm $\approx$\ 247 pixels.}
            \end{figure}
        \end{minipage}
    }
    \put(175,210){
        \begin{minipage}[t]{0.48\linewidth}
            \centering
            \tiny{
            \begin{table}[H]
            \setbeamerfont{caption}{size=\tiny} 
            \captionsetup{skip=0pt,belowskip=0pt}   
            \caption{Mean of measurements shown in Fig.\  1}
            \begin{tabular}{cc}
                \specialrule{1pt}{0pt}{3pt}
                \textbf{Reading} & \textbf{Measurements from } \\
                \textbf{Number}& \textbf{Fig. A \ ($\bm\mu$m)}  \\
                \specialrule{1.5pt}{2pt}{4pt}
                    1 & 121.6\\
                    2 & 117.6\\
                    3 & 121.6\\
                    4 & 137.8\\
                    5 & 121.6\\\specialrule{0.25pt}{2pt}{4pt}
                \textbf{Mean diameter :} & \textbf{124}\\
                \specialrule{1pt}{2pt}{2pt}
            \end{tabular}
            \end{table}
            }
        \end{minipage}
    }
\end{picture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

The frame comes out like this[image]

Comment: In any case, please provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Please find the `MWE` (the way it appears a MWE to me).

Comment: @cfr `figure` and `table` in `beamer` are *not* floats; the class redefines them so they don't float and it's perfectly safe to use them. This is, for example, the redefinition for figure in `beamerbaselocalstructure.sty`: `\newenvironment{figure}[1][]{%
  \def\@captype{figure}%
  \par\nobreak\begin{center}\nobreak}
  {\par\nobreak\end{center}}`

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Thanks. I didn't know that. However, the question is tagged 'floats' which was really the basis of my comment. However, what I should have said in that case was just that the OP is not, in fact, using floats (and that this is a good thing!).

Comment: @cfr;@GonzaloMedina I have removed the tag 'float'. Thanks for your observations. I wanted to tag it with 'figures'. I am surprised that such a tag doesn't seem to be available.

Comment: Your best bet may be to look at how `beamer` defines it and then adapt that rather than trying to fight `beamer`'s configuration. I've cleaned up my comments about floats as they are now inapplicable. Perhaps you could do the same? Also @GonzaloMedina, maybe?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The best way to proceed here is to locally redefine `\abovecaptionskip` and `\belowcaptionskip` (default value=`7pt`). The following example shows this redefinition (it's local since it's done inside an environment):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\mode<presentation> {\usetheme{Madrid}}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Allows including images
\usepackage{booktabs} % Allows the use of \toprule, \midrule and \bottomrule in tables
\usepackage{lmodern}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lm
\usepackage{bm}

\setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Results: Measurement of Length}
    \begin{picture}(0,200)
    \setlength\abovecaptionskip{-5pt}
    \setlength\belowcaptionskip{0pt}
    \put(-5,210){
        \begin{minipage}[t]{0.48\linewidth}
            \setbeamerfont{caption}{size=\tiny} 
            \begin{figure}
                \includegraphics[width=4.5cm, height=3cm]{example-image-a} 
                \caption{Calibration: 1mm $\approx$\ 247 pixels.}
                \label{fig:calibration}
            \end{figure}
        \end{minipage}
    }
    \put(175,200){
        \begin{minipage}[t]{0.48\linewidth}
            \centering
            \tiny{
            \begin{table}[H]
            \setbeamerfont{caption}{size=\tiny} 
            \caption{Mean of measurements shown in Fig.~\ref{fig:calibration}}
            \begin{tabular}{cc}
                \specialrule{1pt}{0pt}{3pt}
                \textbf{Reading} & \textbf{Measurements from } \\
                \textbf{Number}& \textbf{Fig. A \ ($\bm\mu$m)}  \\
                \specialrule{1.5pt}{2pt}{4pt}
                    1 & 121.6\\
                    2 & 117.6\\
                    3 & 121.6\\
                    4 & 137.8\\
                    5 & 121.6\\\specialrule{0.25pt}{2pt}{4pt}
                \textbf{Mean diameter :} & \textbf{124}\\
                \specialrule{1pt}{2pt}{2pt}
            \end{tabular}
            \end{table}
            }
        \end{minipage}
    }
\end{picture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

It's better not to number objects manually for cross-references; the recommended way is to use the standard `\label`, `\ref` mechanism. In your figure I placed a `\label`:

```
\caption{Calibration: 1mm $\approx$\ 247 pixels.}
\label{fig:calibration}
```

and then, in the table, I used `\ref`

```
\caption{Mean of measurements shown in Fig.~\ref{fig:calibration}}
```

(two runs are needed for the cross-reference to appear). I added

```
\setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
```

to the preamble, so figures and tables are explicitly numbered.

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked like magic. I am very happy.